# What sort of fish is this?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

Just saw a meme online with this fish on it. Is this a real fish? Can some aquatic expert identify this for us?

[image: Very blue fish]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is a [blue parrotfish (Scarus coeruleus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_parrotfish):

[image]

(photo: Marc Tarlock via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_parrotfish_(4039797679).jpg))

Comment: Mgk - C'mon. Parrotfish are AMAZING! Some of them can change sexes as adults! They are responsible for most of the sand on earth! They are good eating! You can actually *hear* them crunching coral when snorkeling! Surely you can say more than "this is a parrot fish." (Can you tell I like parrot fish?)